# Implied Volatility as proxy for instantaneous volatility

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility

In many papers and book I have found a reasoning that it is well summarized [in this paper](https://www.princeton.edu/~yacine/stochvol.pdf) as

"*The first proxy we use is an unadjusted Black-Scholes proxy in which the implied volatility of a short-maturity at-the-money option is used in place of the true instantaneous volatility state variable. The use of this proxy is justified in theory by the fact that **the implied volatility of such an option converges to the instantaneous volatility of the logarithmic stock price as the maturity of the option goes to zero**.*"

Where can I find a formal justification of this assertion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of Ledoit et al

Lemma proof in Appendix of http://www.ledoit.net/9-98.pdf

Comment: thanks it is quite useful. Nevertheless I do not see the point in taking a forward call, why not a simple call ?

Answer (score 0):

See also this dissertation by [Durrleman](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~valdo/papers/dissertation.pdf).